# Why is this statement related to linear combinations false?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $Ax=b$, then $b$ must be a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

It is in a linear algebra book. I think it is true, but it is not in fact.
Please let me know what I missed.

Comment: It is true, by definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Maybe there is an error in the answer sheet.

Answer (score 1):

$Ax = b$

Let's represent $A$ as $[C_1, C_2, \dots C_n]$ where each $C_i$ is a column vector of $A$.

We can represent $C_i$ as $[c_{1i}, c_{2i}, \dots c_{mi}]^T$ where $c_{ji}$ is the $j$-th entry in the column $C_i$

Let's represent $x$ as $[x_1, x_2, \dots x_n]^T$ and $b$ as $[b_1, b_2,\dots, b_m]$

Then we know that $b_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{ij}x_j$

Thus let's rewrite $b$ as $[\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{1j}x_j, \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{2j}x_j, \dots, \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{mj}x_j]^T$.

But this is the same as $x_1C_1  + x_2C_2 + \dots x_nC_n$

Thus $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.